# EDITED: How do I find my /home file?

Tags: home-directory

When I installed Ubuntu on my MBP I only made the linux swap partition and the "/" partition. I was looking for my /home file and searched for it but I came up empty handed. I'm guessing I should have installed more folders when I installed Ubuntu what should I do?
Edit: Some of the comments below don't make sense with the edits I've made, so ignore them and look at the answer.

Comment: No idea what you are asking.  Do you mean where is your /home directory?

Comment: I believe so...

Comment: ya thats what i mean

Comment: Hi, what is "MBP" in your question? BTW, `/usr` is an important folder (of many important subfolders and files) whereas "user" is just a short form for the particular user, you or me. So you'll often see `/home/user/Documents/my_important_file.txt` or, in short form, `~/Documents/my_important_file.txt`. In the first case "user" isn't literal: you put in your username with which you log in.

Comment: @DKBose MacBook Pro (I'm guessing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you look for it? Try entering `cd ~` in a terminal window. That should take you there. By the way, it would be `/usr` not `/user`.

Comment: /usr is not related if you got the meat of the question right.  Still upvote since it's probably mostly right.

Comment: I'm guessing that you meant i should do cd~/usr or cd~ /usr. I tried both but it says that command doesn't work. Did I enter it wrong?

Comment: no .. you just need to enter `cd ~`

Comment: @rajlego `/usr/` has nothing to do with your home folder. Homes are stored under `/home/userName/`. `~` is a shortcut to your home.

Comment: Note that 'cd ~' because 'cd' also works afaik.